# How can I prove that a multivariable real vector valued function is continuous iff its component functions are continuous?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, epsilon-delta

Suppose we have a multivariable, real, vector-valued function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}^m$ where $f = (f_1, f_2, ..., f_m)$. How can I prove that $f$ is continuous iff all of its component functions $f_i$ are continuous? This is where where $f_i$ is a multivariable, real function $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \to  \mathbb{R}$

FORWARDS:

suppose that $f$ is continuous and $a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$\implies \forall a, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $d(a, x) < \delta \implies d(f(a), f(x)) < \epsilon$

$\implies ||f(x) - f(a)|| < \epsilon$

$\implies \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{m}(f_i(x) - f_i(a))^2} < \epsilon$

$\implies \sum_{i = 1}^{m}(f_i(x) - f_i(a))^2 < \epsilon^2$

$\implies (f_i(x) - f_i(a))^2\ < \epsilon^2$

$\implies |f_i(x) - f_i(a)| < \epsilon$

BACKWARDS:

suppose that each $f_i$ is continuous and $a = (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$

$\implies \forall a, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_i > 0$ s.t. $d(a, x) < \delta_i \implies d(f_i(a), f_i(x)) < \epsilon$

if we let $\delta = min\{\delta_1, \delta_2, ..., \delta_n\}$ , we can say that...

$\implies \forall a, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $d(a, x) < \delta \implies d(f_i(a), f_i(x)) < \epsilon$

Now, because the above statement holds true $\forall \epsilon$, we can say that...

$\implies \forall a, \forall \epsilon > 0,\exists \delta > 0$ s.t. $d(a, x) < \delta \implies d(f_i(a), f_i(x)) < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{m}}$

$\implies |f_i(x) - f_i(a)| < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{m}}$

$\implies (f_i(x) - f_i(a))^2 < (\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{m}})^2$

$\implies \sum_{i = 1}^{m}(f_i(x) - f_i(a))^2\ < m(\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{m}})^2 = \epsilon^2$

$\implies \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^{m}(f_i(x) - f_i(a))^2} < \epsilon$

$\implies ||f(x) - f(a)|| < \epsilon$

Also, does this proof only hold true when d is the stadard euclidean distance on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$. Why would other norms or metrics suffice? I've seen a few other posts online about this proof. However, I'm still unsure about a few things.

Comment: This question already asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307290/continuity-of-a-vector-function-through-continuity-of-its-components

Comment: Do you know some general topology (for example, the product topology)?

Comment: I've been studying topology a lot this past month. Not so much product topology. I've found that If the real line has standard topology, then the product topology on the product of n copies of $\mathbb{R}$  is equal to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. I think this somewhat sense how the topologies coincide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct - but yes, it is based on the Euclidean distance $d(a,b) =  \lVert a - b \rVert_2$. Note that I write $\lVert -\rVert_2$ instead of $\lVert -\rVert$; the latter symbol will be used to denote an *arbitrary* norm. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). Your proof only requires to know that for $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_m)$
$$\lvert y_i \rvert =\sqrt{y_i^2} \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m y_i^2} = \lVert y \rVert_2 \tag{1} ,$$
$$\lVert y \rVert_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m y_i^2} \le \sqrt{m \max_{i=1}^m y_i^2} = \sqrt m \sqrt{ \max_{i=1}^m y_i^2} = m  \max_{i=1}^m\sqrt{y_i^2} = \sqrt m  \max_{i=1}^m \lvert y_i \rvert \tag{2} .$$

The expression
$$\lVert y \rVert_\infty = \max_{i=1}^m \lvert y_i \rvert$$
is known as the *maximum norm* on $\mathbb R^m$. From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get
$$\lVert y \rVert_\infty \le \lVert y \rVert_2 \le \sqrt m \lVert y \rVert_\infty \tag{3} .$$
There are many other norms on $\mathbb R^m$, e.g. the *taxicab norm* $\lVert y \rVert_1 = \sum_{i=1}^m \lvert y_i \rvert$.

Norms $\lVert - \rVert$ and $\lVert - \rVert'$ on a vector space $V$ are called equivalent if there exist $a, b >0$ such that $\lVert y \rVert \le a \lVert y \rVert'$ and $\lVert y \rVert' \le b \lVert y \rVert$ for all $y$. Clearly this is equivalent to the existence of $A, B > 0$ such that $A\lVert y \rVert \le \lVert y \rVert' \le B \lVert y \rVert$ for all $y$.

$(3)$ says therefore that the Euclidean norm and the maximum norm are equivalent.

It is easy to verify that two norms are equivalent if and only if they induce the same topology on $V$. A more interesting fact is that **all norms on a finite-dimensional $V$ are equivalent**. See [Equivalence of Norms on Finite-Dimensional Spaces: Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4300563/equivalence-of-norms-on-finite-dimensional-spaces-proof).

In many special cases one can verify the equivalence of norms by simple individual proofs; see $(1)$ and $(2)$ above. As an easy exercise we can prove that $\lVert - \rVert_\infty$ and $\lVert - \rVert_1$ are equivalent:
$$\lVert y \rVert_\infty = \max_{i=1}^m \lvert y_i \rvert \le \sum_{i=1}^m \lvert y_i \rvert = \lVert y \rVert_1 \le m \max_{i=1}^m \lvert y_i \rvert = m \lVert y \rVert_\infty . \tag{4}$$

Thus your result is true for **any** norm on $\mathbb R^m$, but the general proof requires to know that all norms are equivalent.

Anyway, your original proof can easily be adapted to work for $\lVert - \rVert_1$ and $\lVert - \rVert_\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Correct me if I'm wrong here: If we have a continuous function $f$ that is between two metric spaces (X, d) and (Y, d) , it's true that no matter which norm we equip with X and Y,  the norm will always induce standard topology on the sets X and Y as long as X and Y are of finite dimension. One question, suppose we have a Euclidean norm on X and a taxicab norm on Y where X and Y are of finite dimension. Could f still be continuous? I assume this is true since I believe X and Y would both have standard topology.

Comment: @AdamS You should not consider arbitrary metric spaces, but normed linear spaces $X,Y$. Then all norms induce the same topology and you can denote this topology as the *standard topology*.  And yes, the continuity of a map $f : X \to Y$ only depends on the topologies of $X,Y$ which are the standard ones here.